# Evaluation of $\int_{C} \frac{e^{-xz/(1-z)}}{(1-z)^{\alpha + 1}z^{n+1}}dz$ where C is positively oriented circle with |z| < 1

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been stuck on this question for way to long. We must evaluate 
$\int_{C} \frac{e^{-xz/(1-z)}}{(1-z)^{\alpha + 1}z^{n+1}}dz$ 
Where C is a positively oriented circle with radius smaller than 1. In the previous subquestion we are asked to evaluate 
$f_n(\alpha, x) = \frac{x ^{-\alpha}e^x}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x}x^{n + \alpha})$ 
for n=0,1,2 where I found 
$f_0(\alpha, x) = 0$ 
$f_1(\alpha, x) = (-x + (1 + \alpha) * 1) = 1 + \alpha - x$ 
$f_2(\alpha, x) =\frac{1}{2}(x^2 - 2(2 + \alpha)x + (2+\alpha)(1+\alpha))$ 
I suspect I need to use this to solve the integral, however I just do not see how.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem? The integrand function has a pole of order $n+1$ in $z=0$

Comment: I have not the residue theorem yet.

Comment: This is weird. It can be easily solved by using [the residue theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), but without It i honestly can't think to anything

Comment: Apparently we where only meant to solve for the first 3 terms when using Cauchy's integral theorem for derivatives. Then we could see that it had the same results as $f_n(\alpha, x)$ (except for a factor of $2\pi i$) for these first 3 terms and we could assume it would be equal to this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when working out the integral for the first 3 terms using Cauchy's integral theorem for derivatives

$f^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z - z_0)^{n+1}}dz$,

you are able to show that

$\int_{C} \frac{e^{-xz/(1-z)}}{(1-z)^{\alpha + 1}z^{n+1}}dz = 2 \pi if_n(\alpha, x)$

for these first 3 terms (I do not know if this holds for all n).